# How handle streaming error with AVPlayer

Tags: error-handling, streaming, audio-streaming, avplayer, key-value-observing

I use AVPlayer to stream tracks.I'm trying to handle all errors like network unavailable or stream unaivalable
But I find any handler for this kind of error.

I've already added a KVO for on the avplayer's status.

```
 [self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
```

But even the stream doesn't exist (example: wrong url), the status switch to AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay.

EDIT

Solution was to work with AVPLayerItems and use AVQueuPlayer. The other problem was I reallocated this player at every tracks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add KVO to AVPlayerItem instead of AVPlayer with NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew as well.

```
[playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
[self.player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

Comment: Yes the solution was to observe the AVPlayerItem and not the player.

Answer (score 1):

There is a notification you shall subscribe

```
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(_itemDidError:) name:AVPlayerItemNewErrorLogEntryNotification object:_playerItem];
```

But that won't solve all the problem. I see it will not fire in the case like 404