# m3u8 file doesnt play in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, m3u8, avplayerviewcontroller

Hello I want to play m3u8 file using swift. My m3u8 file structure is like this.

```
#EXTM3U

#EXT-X-VERSION:3

#EXT-X-STREAM- INF:BANDWIDTH=814508,CODECS="avc1.66.51,mp4a.40.34",RESOLUTION=720x576 chunklist_w247403833.m3u8
```

But this is not playing. But if I used apple sample m3u8 file in [here](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/102w0bsn0ge83qfv7za/102/hls_vod_mvp.m3u8) its playing. but above m3u8 file is playing in android app and windows vlc player too. What would be the reason for this? Please help me.
Thanks

**code**

```
 let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://74.208.128.124:1935/live/myStream/playlist.m3u8")//http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/102w0bsn0ge83qfv7za/102/hls_vod_mvp.m3u8
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()
}
```

**Adding KVO**

```
 override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
   if keyPath=="status"
   {
      if(player.status==AVPlayerStatus.readyToPlay)
      {
        print(player.status)
      }
    else if(player.status==AVPlayerStatus.failed)
      {
        print("ERROR-----------", player.status)
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: What's your code? Did you get a `AVPlayerStatus` and the corresponding error?

Comment: Try to add KVO listen to the status, like there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401437/knowing-when-avplayer-object-is-ready-to-play I guess that looking for "KVO + Swift" + the question may help you. You may be able to get the reason of the fail.

Comment: Thanks. I added the KVO and it never print my Error log, its going into if(player.status==AVPlayerStatus.readyToPlay) and it just print AVPlayerStatus in the log

Comment: In case of `AVPlayerStatus.failed`, try to read `player.error`? Else, look there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004313/how-handle-streaming-error-with-avplayer it may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this framework. It worked for me.

pod 'Keith'

For a sample project download this and check
https://github.com/Movile/Keith

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some other player like node player. According to me, AVplayer is not a good option to play m3u8 format or for live streaming. Even if the video plays, there will be lag while playing it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar issue using AVPlayerItem to store the reference to the AVAsset.

```
@IBOutlet weak var videoContainer: UIView!
var player: AVPlayer?
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
var urlM3u8 = URL(string:"http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/102w0bsn0ge83qfv7za/102/hls_vod_mvp.m3u8")

 func videoPlayer(url: URL){
    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
    playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    playerLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
    playerLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.videoContainer.frame.width, height: self.videoContainer.frame.height)
    videoContainer.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
    player?.play()
}
```